# Add target attribute dynamically to <a> which is present in JS variable as HTML codeblock

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
var ab = "Solution to the <a href='https://testflow'>Test Data(DT)</a> for given query is resolved."
```

How to identify  anchor tag from the inner HTML text and add target attribute into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery's `.html()` along with an in-memory div to parse the string, manipulate it and then convert it back to a string:

```js
var ab = "Solution to the <a href='https://testflow'>Test Data(DT)</a> for given query is resolved.";

var wrapper = $("<div>").html(ab);
wrapper.find("a").attr("target", "_blank");
ab = wrapper.html();

console.log(ab);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```